# applet not running even after adding it's URL to exception list

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to run a Java applet. Chrome not support it so I am trying it with IE. I have added the URL to exception list, but it is still showing error that "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running."

Details:

```
Java Plug-in 11.91.2.15
Using JRE version 1.8.0_91-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Hp
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1631f2d
security: Expected Main URL: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/NewApplet.class
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/NewApplet.class, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/, version: null]
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.91
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.91
basic: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: JUT Record:
    plugin2 denied [by security settings]
    file://F:\cs infotech\july 14\JavaLibrary1\build\NewApplet.html: launchjnlp= code=NewApplet.class codebase=file:///F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes width=350 height=200  app_model=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
basic: exception: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running.
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
    at com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedDialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.checkRunLocal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.checkUnsignedSandboxSecurity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1631f2d
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@12ffba8
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@149e612
security: Expected Main URL: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/NewApplet.class
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/NewApplet.class, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes/, version: null]
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.91
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.91
basic: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
security: JUT Record:
    plugin2 denied [by security settings]
    file://F:\cs infotech\july 14\JavaLibrary1\build\NewApplet.html: launchjnlp= code=NewApplet.class codebase=file:///F:/cs%20infotech/july%2014/JavaLibrary1/build/classes width=350 height=200  app_model=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
basic: exception: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running.
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
    at com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedDialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.checkRunLocal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.checkUnsignedSandboxSecurity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@149e612
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).